# Ajuda com broken pipe

Tags: jsf, hibernate, jpa

Galera, estou com um problema no meu sistema, ele esta caindo demais a conexão como banco de dados, esse sistema chega a ficar ate 12h ocioso, estou precisando de uma ajuda pra configurar o C3P

```
<!--Configuração do pool de c3p0         -->
<property name="c3p0.acquire_increment"         value="10"    /> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size"        value="20"     />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size"        value="50"   />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout"         value="144000"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"  value="50"    /> 
<property name="c3p0.idle_test_period"          value="3000"   />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique no seu MySQL a variável `wait_timeout`. Talvez ela esteja com um tempo menor do que o que vc configurou no C3P0 `idle_test_period`

Answer (score 0):

eu tive um problema parecido quando fui testar o meu TC, a solução que encontrei foi aplicar os seguintes atributos no Persistence.xml. Se não tiver resolvido ainda, tente esses parametros no xml do hibernate.

```
 <property name="connection.autoReconnect" value="true"/>
 <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Opa brother ... cara, ainda nao consegui, falei com o pessoal do Integrator e nao deu certo .. Vou testar sua sugestão cara .. muito obrigado ...